# Flexbox - 5 columns in first row and 6 columns in second row

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a layout that's using Flexbox and I am trying to figure out how to break my 11 elements into 2 rows. The place where I'm having issues is breaking out the elements into 2 rows where the first row has 5 columns and the second row has 6 columns but all 11 elements are the same width. Like this:

[image: Desired layout]

Here's what I have so far:

```css
.container {
  display:flex;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
  justify-content:space-around;
}
.ele {
  flex-grow:1;
  height:100px;
  width:calc(100% * (1/6) - 2px);
  border:1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="ele">Element</div>
  <div class="ele">Element</div>
  <div class="ele">Element</div>
  <div class="ele">Element</div>
  <div class="ele">Element</div>
  <div class="ele">Element</div>
  <div class="ele">Element</div>
  <div class="ele">Element</div>
  <div class="ele">Element</div>
  <div class="ele">Element</div>
  <div class="ele">Element</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you can do is to make use of the pseudo elements.

Here I positioned the `::before` before the 1st `ele` and the `::after` after the 5th `ele` (using the `order` property), made them half the width of the `ele`, so they push the last 6 to the next row and at the same time center the first 5.

```css
.container {
  display:flex;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
  justify-content:space-around;
}
.ele {
  height:100px;
  flex-basis: calc(100% / 6);
  border:1px solid black;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.container::after,
.container::before {
  content: '';
  flex-basis: calc(100% / 12);
}
.container::after {
  order: 1;
}
.ele:nth-child(n+6) {
  order: 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="ele">Element</div>
  <div class="ele">Element</div>
  <div class="ele">Element</div>
  <div class="ele">Element</div>
  <div class="ele">Element</div>
  <div class="ele">Element</div>
  <div class="ele">Element</div>
  <div class="ele">Element</div>
  <div class="ele">Element</div>
  <div class="ele">Element</div>
  <div class="ele">Element</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using 11 items, use 12.

Then hide the 6th item on the first row.

Make sure the hidden item has at least 1px width, to ensure the 7th item wraps to the next row.

Add a pseudo-element with 1px width as the first item, in order to balance out the 1px at the end of the row, and establish perfect centering.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.ele {
  height: 100px;
  width: calc(100% / 6);
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.hidden {
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 1px;
  border: none;
}

.container::before {
  content: "";
  width: 1px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="ele">Element</div>
  <div class="ele">Element</div>
  <div class="ele">Element</div>
  <div class="ele">Element</div>
  <div class="ele">Element</div>
  <div class="ele hidden">Element</div>
  <div class="ele">Element</div>
  <div class="ele">Element</div>
  <div class="ele">Element</div>
  <div class="ele">Element</div>
  <div class="ele">Element</div>
  <div class="ele">Element</div>
</div>
```